# How can I make jq discard all numbers except the largest one in a series?

Tags: bash, jq

A script calls Amazon ECS and gets list images to find the latest version:

```
BACKEND_VERSION=$(aws ecr describe-images --repository-name laplacelab-backend-repo --query \
  'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*]' --output json
```

Removing the irrelevant portions, the output is of the following form:

```
[
    {"imageTags": ["v2"]},
    {"imageTags": ["v1"]}
]
```

...so the largest number can be incremented with the following code:

```sh
jq '( .[].imageTags[] | select(startswith("v")) | ltrimstr("v") | tonumber | .+1 ) // 1'
```

...as can be tested as follows:

```sh
jq '( .[].imageTags[] | select(startswith("v")) | ltrimstr("v") | tonumber | .+1 ) // 1' <<EOF
[
    {"imageTags": ["v2"]},
    {"imageTags": ["v1"]}
]
EOF
```

...emitting the desired output:

```
3
2
```

However, this doesn't handle the case when more than one tag exists for an image:

```
[
    {"imageTags": ["v4","v3"]},
    {"imageTags": ["v1","v2"]}
]
```

...in which case our current output is:

```
5
4
2
3
```

...but the desired output is:

```
5
3
```

How can I modify the script to take only the highest version number when multiple tags exist?

Comment: Please provide specific sample input we can actually run to reproduce your problem (and that will have a specific correct output when everything works, clearly defined in the question) -- not mockups that aren't actually real JSON and thus can't be run through jq or used to test proposed answers.

Comment: ...that said, your goal is just to get the _largest_ value in a list, after stripping a prefix from each entry and parsing them as a number? Arguably that could be asked on its own without involving all the extra complexity of AWS. (Also, I'm not sure there's a reason to have the bash tag here at all -- this can be done purely in jq code with no logic performed by bash).

Comment: @Charles Duffy last peace of code is a real example. When everything works in `BACKEND_VERSION` contain number `1` or `2` last fined version +1

Comment: @Charles Duffy add real input

Comment: Ahh -- I already had an edit underway. (You'll see that the new version still keeps the code minimal, but it's minimal while _actually being JSON someone can test_).

Comment: ...as for the "real example", the original version wasn't useful to people who didn't have the `aws` tool and an account to run it against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split across lines to allow indentation to reveal structure, consider:

```
jq '
(
  .[].imageTags
  | [
      .[]
      | select(startswith("v"))
      | ltrimstr("v")
      | tonumber
    ]
  | max
  | .+1
) // 1'
```

Note that we're generating a list from each `imageTags` entry and finding the `max` entry in that list before incrementing it.

If you just wanted the maximum *overall* -- a single number for each input document, not a single number per `imageTags` list -- this becomes even simpler:

```
jq '
(
  [
    .[].imageTags[]
    | select(startswith("v"))
    | ltrimstr("v")
    | tonumber
  ]
  | max
  | .+1
) // 1'
```